# How to control WebView's content anytime on Android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to create an app which uses a WebView and if I click on "logout" it should return me to the MainActivity.

I've been taking a look [at this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation) but I can just check it when it's loaded for the first time, not every "link" I open once it's loaded.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this and works like a charm!

```
browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

  browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
  {
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
      {   // Method to control if the users logs of INSIDE the WebView
         if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.google.com"))
        {
            Log.e("Inside shouldOverride", "Equals www.google.com");
           return false;
        }
         Log.e("Inside shouldOverride", "It's not google.com. Going to MainActivity");
         Intent intent = new Intent(WebActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         return true;
      }
  });
```